# Orika: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object cannot be cast to mapper.Name

Tags: java, orika

I'm doing sample example orika mapper documentation in [here](https://orika-mapper.github.io/orika-docs/mappings-via-classmapbuilder.html) section **Mapping elements of Arrays and Lists**.

Below is my code to create mapperFacade and convert `Person` object to `PersonDto` -

Name class definition -

```
    public class Name {
        private String first;
        private String last;
        private String fullName;
        // getters/setters

        public Name() {

        }

        public Name(String first, String last, String fullName) {
            this.first = first;
            this.last = last;
            this.fullName = fullName;
        }

        public String getFirst() {
            return first;
        }

        public void setFirst(String first) {
            this.first = first;
        }

        public String getLast() {
            return last;
        }

        public void setLast(String last) {
            this.last = last;
        }

        public String getFullName() {
            return fullName;
        }

        public void setFullName(String fullName) {
            this.fullName = fullName;
        }
    }
```

Person class definition -

```
import java.util.List;

public class Person {
 private List<Name> names;
 // getters/setters


 public Person() {
 }

public List<Name> getNames() {
    return names;
}

 public void setNames(List<Name> names) {
    this.names = names;
 }
}
```

PersonDto class definition -

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class PersonDto {
    private Map<String, Name> personalNames;
    private String[] firstNames;
    private List<String> lastNames;
    // getters/setters omitted

    public PersonDto() {
    }

    public Map<String, Name> getPersonalNames() {
        return personalNames;
    }

    public void setPersonalNames(Map<String, Name> personalNames) {
        this.personalNames = personalNames;
    }

    public String[] getFirstNames() {
        return firstNames;
    }

    public void setFirstNames(String[] firstNames) {
        this.firstNames = firstNames;
    }

    public List<String> getLastNames() {
        return lastNames;
    }

    public void setLastNames(List<String> lastNames) {
        this.lastNames = lastNames;
    }
}


    Map<String,String> fieldMap = new HashMap<>();
    fieldMap.put("names{fullName}", "personalNames{key}");
    fieldMap.put("names{}", "personalNames{value}");
    MapperFactory mapperFactory = new DefaultMapperFactory.Builder().mapNulls(false).dumpStateOnException(false).build();
    ClassMapBuilder<Person, PersonDto> classBuilder = mapperFactory.classMap(Person.class, PersonDto.class);
    fieldMap.forEach((k,v) -> classBuilder.field(k,v));
    classBuilder.register();
    BoundMapperFacade<Person, PersonDto> delegate = mapperFactory.getMapperFacade(Person.class, PersonDto.class);



    Person person = new Person();
    Name n1 = new Name("raj", "kumar", "raj kumar");
    Name n2 = new Name("senthil", "kumar", "senthil kumar");
    person.setNames(Arrays.asList(n1, n2));
    PersonDto pDto = mapper.map(person);
    System.out.println(pDto);
```

When I run this code, I get below error -

> java.lang.Object cannot be cast to mapper.Name
>   java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object cannot be cast to mapper.Name
>     at ma.glasnost.orika.generated.Orika_PersonDto_Person_Mapper12572858142441$0.mapAtoB(Orika_PersonDto_Person_Mapper12572858142441$0.java)
>     at ma.glasnost.orika.impl.mapping.strategy.UseCustomMapperStrategy.map(UseCustomMapperStrategy.java:77)
>     at ma.glasnost.orika.impl.DefaultBoundMapperFacade.map(DefaultBoundMapperFacade.java:137)
>     at ma.glasnost.orika.impl.DefaultBoundMapperFacade.map(DefaultBoundMapperFacade.java:94)
>     at mapper.PersonToPersonDtoMapper.map(PersonToPersonDtoMapper.java:29)
>     at mapper.PersonToPersonDtoMapper.map(PersonToPersonDtoMapper.java:14)
>     at mapper.PersonToPersonDtoMapperTest.test1(PersonToPersonDtoMapperTest.java:29)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>     at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:133)
>     at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeMethod(TestInvoker.java:584)
>     at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethod(TestInvoker.java:172)
>     at org.testng.internal.MethodRunner.runInSequence(MethodRunner.java:46)
>     at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:804)
>     at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:145)
>     at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:146)
>     at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
>     at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1249)
>     at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:770)
>     at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:591)
>     at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:402)
>     at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:396)
>     at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:355)
>     at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:304)

I have this code hosted on github [here](https://github.com/rajcspsg/orika-demo/blob/master/orika-1.5/src/test/java/mapper/PersonToPersonDtoMapperTest.java#L16-L20).

What is wrong with my code? How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Please provide the full classes so we can compare the stack trace to the code.

Comment: @ChristophGrimmer-Dietrich I've updated the full class definition and also the link to github repository. Please let me know if you need more details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue happens because Java Generics are stripped out in runtime. `Map.Entry<String, Name>` (compile time) becomes `Map.Entry<Object, Object>` (runtime).

You can overcome the problem by adjusting the ClassMapBuilder as follows:

```java
Map<String, String> fieldMap = new HashMap<>();
fieldMap.put("names{fullName}", "personalNames{key}");
fieldMap.put("names{}", "personalNames{value}");
MapperFactory mapperFactory = new DefaultMapperFactory.Builder().mapNulls(false).dumpStateOnException(false).build();
// Swap Person, PersonDto generic arguments.
ClassMapBuilder<PersonDto, Person> classBuilder = mapperFactory.classMap(PersonDto.class, Person.class);
fieldMap.forEach((k, v) -> classBuilder.field(v, k));
classBuilder.register();
// rest of the code is the same
```